# Recursively iterate over an array to change specific key's value

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$a = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => array(
        'key4' => 'value4',
        'key5' => array(
            'key6' => 'value6'
        )
    )
);
```

as you can see there are inner arrays inside `$a`

Now, I have a list of keys, example:

```
key1
key4
key6
```

I need a script that search if those key exists, and if exists change their values.
I Need to change their values with `base64_encode($value_of_the_key)`

so Maybe a callback that get the current value and convert it using base64_encode() function.

COuld someone help me?

I'm tring to see the current php functions but it seems there is not ones that do this thing.

THanks

**EDIT:**

Using the follow code i can get the keys in the callback....but the problem is:

How can i modify the values directly in the array? I Mean.... ok ... i get key and value, but how to change the value in the original array? (`$a`)

```
$a = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => array(
        'key4' => 'value4',
        'key5' => array(
            'key6' => 'value6'
        )
    )
);


function test($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item<br />\n";
}


array_walk_recursive($a, 'test');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_walk_recursive()` with callback supplied should help. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: thank you for the reply, but please take a look at the edit i made in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Dail use `function test(&$item, $key)` (note the `&`) and modify `$item` inside the function.